# ical4j Api, create new notification with OOF status

Tags: java, outlook, icalendar

I am creating a new event calendar using ical4j plugin. I am using outlook to receive this notification.
This one must be show like an "absense" ( Out Of Office).

For this, i use property X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS = OOF.
When i receive this notification, in outlook, it looks like "busy" and not like "out of office".

Heres it content of .ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140324T121412Z
DTSTART:20140804T000000
DTEND:20140805T000000
SUMMARY:absense
ATTENDEE;CN=Resp 1;RSVP=FALSE:mailto:toto.toto@test.com
SEQUENCE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:TENTATIVE
ORGANIZER;CN=res:mailto:etoto.toto@test.com
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:123456789123456789aabbcc
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:OOF
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:TRUE
CREATED:20140324T121412Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

how can i do, to have the correct status of this notification in outlook ? is there something incorrect in my file ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You mention **receiving** this REQUEST. If we translate this in iTIP workflow, we have etoto.toto@test.com (ORGANIZER) inviting toto.toto@test.com (ATTENDEE) to an event. So on the Outlook side (attendee side), you are receiving an invitation.
It would be weird if any arbitrary organizer could set **your** freebusy status to Out of Office, don't you think.
In other words, I think it make sense for Outlook to ignore the X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS.

On the other hand, if you remove the METHOD, ORGANIZER and ATTENDEE properties, and if you import the event, you may see the OOF value being taken into account (have not tried it myself).

Comment: yes, if you don't have METHOD, ORGANIZER and ATTENDEE properties, the X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:OOF works as expected